# Translate GTK UI written in Glade and Python

Tags: python, translation, pygtk, glade, pygobject

I've spent some time looking around for answers, and I've got a ton of them. And theoretically my code should work, however it doesn't. 
At first I'll post the minimal code, after that I'll describe the problems.

test.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="default_width">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">File</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Edit</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label3">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Find</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label4">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">View</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label5">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Document</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

test.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join, realpath
import gettext
import locale

APP = 'myapp'
WHERE_AM_I = abspath(dirname(realpath(__file__)))
LOCALE_DIR = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'mo')

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.getlocale())
locale.bindtextdomain(APP, LOCALE_DIR)
gettext.bindtextdomain(APP, LOCALE_DIR)
gettext.textdomain(APP)
_ = gettext.gettext

print('Using locale directory: {}'.format(LOCALE_DIR))

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Build GUI
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'test.glade')
        self.builder.set_translation_domain(APP)
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

        print(_('File'))
        print(_('Edit'))
        print(_('Find'))
        print(_('View'))
        print(_('Document'))

        # Get objects
        go = self.builder.get_object
        self.window = go('window')

        # Connect signals
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        # Everything is ready
        self.window.show()

    def main_quit(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = MyApp()
    Gtk.main()
```

en.po :

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-06-15 15:18+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: test.glade:66
msgid "Document"
msgstr "Dokumentumok"

#: test.glade:30
msgid "Edit"
msgstr "Szerkesztés"

#: test.glade:18
msgid "File"
msgstr "Fájl"

#: test.glade:42
msgid "Find"
msgstr "Keresés"

#: test.glade:54
msgid "View"
msgstr "Nézet"
```

And the myapp.mo file is in **mo/hu_HU/LC_MESSAGES/myapp.mo**

Problem:

The strings in the python code are translated perfectly (so when I use set_label it works also), but the strings in the glade file won't work, even though they're translated successfully. So the problem isn't with the loading of the locale.

Output :

```
Using locale directory: /home/daniel/Downloads/test/mo
Fájl
Szerkesztés
Keresés
Nézet
Dokumentumok
```

GUI :
[image]

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome desktop, and the system language is the target language (hu_HU)

Comment: as for me in place of `CHARSET` you should put some correct value - ie. `UTF-8` - `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"`. Word `CHARSET` is not correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works for me when I use correct encoding in place of word `CHARSET` in `en.po` - ie. `UTF-8`

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n".
```

[image]

---

**BTW:**

When I use in console/terminal

```
msgfmt -c en.po -o myapp.mo
```

then it even shows warning

```
en.po: warning: Charset "CHARSET" is not a portable encoding name.
                Message conversion to user's charset might not work.
```

and it confirms that `CHARSET` has to be changed.

---

It shows also warnings for other values - `PACKAGE VERSION`, `YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE`, `FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>`, `LANGUAGE`
 - but they are not so important.

```
po/en.po:7: warning: header field 'Project-Id-Version' still has the initial default value
po/en.po:7: warning: header field 'PO-Revision-Date' still has the initial default value
po/en.po:7: warning: header field 'Last-Translator' still has the initial default value
po/en.po:7: warning: header field 'Language-Team' still has the initial default value
po/en.po:7: warning: header field 'Language' still has the initial default value
```

---

**EDIT:**

it seems code sets `LC_ALL` - `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ...)` but in my system (Linux Mint 19.2 based on Ubuntu 18.04) I have also `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8`, `LANGUAGE=pl_PL:pl` and maybe it makes difference. But I can't set it in code `locale.setlocale(locale.LANG, ...)`

**EDIT:**

You confirmed that variable `LANGUAGE` was the problem.

If `LANGUAGE` is `hu:en` or `hu` then `.mo` file has to be in folder `hu` instead of `hu_HU`

---

**BTW:**

I checked I have also folder `hu` in `/usr/share/locale/` but when I run

```
locale -a | grep hu
```

then it shows me

```
hu_HU
hu_HU.UTF-8
```

And `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'hu')` gives me error but `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'hu_HU')` runs without error.

I created two folders with different words `mo/hu_HU/...` and `mo/pl_PL/...` and even if I use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'hu_HU')` I see words from `pl_PL` . But when I remove `locale.setlocale()` then I see English words.

To see words from `hu_HU` I have to run it in console as

```
 LANGUAGE=hu_HU python test.py
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really a dumb thing from me... Now the example works (at least it runs) but it produces the same problem as the actual program: the GUI is still in english.
Updated question to show.

Comment: check what you have in `print( locale.getlocale() )`. If you get `en_GB` then you have to put it in `mo/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/myapp.mo`  I get `pl_PL` and I had to put in `mo/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/myapp.mo`

Comment: I've got `('hu_HU', 'UTF-8')` in `locale.getlocale()` output, as this is the system language. And the print outputs are translated without a problem. So that's my problem: everything seems perfect, but still won't work.

Comment: it seems code sets `LC_ALL`  - `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ...)` but in my system (Linux Mint 19.2 based on Ubuntu 18.04) I have also `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8`, `LANGUAGE=pl_PL:pl` and maybe it makes difference. But I can't set it in code `locale.setlocale(locale.LANG, ...)`

Comment: BTW: I found [Translating python gtk builder files](https://martens.me/programming/translating-python-gtk-builder-files.html) and there is information that `Gtk.Builder()` may need some extra settings in system which `gettext.gettext()` doesn't need it.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the article that you've mentioned, and I bookmarked it as a future workaround in the worst case (if the cleaner way won't work). 

Regarding your previous answer, the `$LANGUAGE` variable was the problem: for me it's `hu:en` or on my other PC (linux mint) `hu`. So I've changed the folder name from hu_HU to hu and it's working!! Thank you! And as an evidence I've looked into `/usr/share/locale/` and I saw that every folder there is also just the simple language code without territory code.

If you can edit your answer according to this I'll mark it as solution.